# Removing duplicate rows with ddply

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataframe `df` containing two factor variables (Var and Year) as well as one (in reality several) column with values.

```
df <- structure(list(Var = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("2000", "2001", 
"2002"), class = "factor"), Val = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("2", "3", "4", "5", "8", 
"9"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Var", "Year", "Val"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")

> df
   Var Year Val
1    A 2000   2
2    A 2001   3
3    A 2002   3
4    B 2000   5
5    B 2001   2
6    B 2002   4
7    B 2002   4
8    C 2000   8
9    C 2001   9
10   C 2002   9
```

Now I'd like to find rows with the same value for `Val` for each `Var` and `Year` and only keep one of those. So in this example I would like row 7 to be removed.

I've tried to find a solution with `plyr` using something like 
`df_new <- ddply(df, .(Var, Year), summarise, !duplicate(Val))` 
but obviously that is not a function accepted by `ddply`.

I found this [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14590127/exclude-duplicate-values-in-certain-columns-using-ddply) question but the `plyr` solution by Arun only gives me a dataframe with 0 rows and 0 columns and I do not understand the answer well enough to modify it according to my needs.

Any hints on how to go about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just used the unique() function instead of !duplicate(Val)

```
df_new <- ddply(df, .(Var, Year), summarise, Val=unique(Val))
# or
df_new <- ddply(df, .(Var, Year), function(x) x[!duplicated(x$Val),])
# or if you only have these 3 columns:
df_new <- ddply(df, .(Var, Year), unique)
# with dplyr
df%.%group_by(Var, Year)%.%filter(!duplicated(Val))
```

hth

Comment: awesome, thanks! the 2nd one does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Non-duplicates of `Val` by `Var` and `Year` are the same as non-duplicates of `Val`, `Var`, and `Year`. You can specify several columns for `duplicated` (or the whole data frame).

I think this does what you'd like.

```
df[!duplicated(df), ]
```

Or.

```
df[!duplicated(df[, c("Var", "Year", "Val")]), ]
```

Comment: thanks, the 2nd one works great, too! Didn't expect it to be that easy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the plyr package here. If your whole dataset consists of only these 3 columns and you need to remove the duplicates, then you can use,

```
df_new <- unique(df)
```

Else, if you need to just pick up the first observation for a group by variable list, then you can use the method suggested by Richard. That's usually how I have been doing it.