# R: how to remove duplicate rows by column

Tags: r, duplicates

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2),
                 gender = c("Female", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"),
                 variant = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"))
> df
  id gender variant
1  1 Female       a
2  1 Female       b
3  1   Male       c
4  2 Female       d
5  2   Male       e
```

I want to remove duplicate rows in my data.frame according to the `gender` column in my data set. I know there has been a similar question asked ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011246/deleting-rows-that-are-duplicated-in-one-column-based-on-the-conditions-of-anoth)) but the difference here is that I would like to remove duplicate rows within each subset of the data set, where each subset is defined by an unique `id`.

My desired result is this:

```
  id gender variant
1  1 Female       a
3  1   Male       c
4  2 Female       d
5  2   Male       e
```

I've tried the following and it works, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner, more efficient way of doing this?

```
out = list()
for(i in 1:2){
  df2 <- subset(df, id == i)
  out[[i]] <- df2[!duplicated(df2$gender), ]
}
do.call(rbind.data.frame, out)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicated rows using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959635/remove-duplicated-rows-using-dplyr) OR [Removing duplicate rows with ddply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23079248/removing-duplicate-rows-with-ddply)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
df[!duplicated(df[ , c("id","gender")]),]

#     id  gender  variant
#  1   1  Female     a
#  3   1   Male      c
#  4   2  Female     d
#  5   2   Male      e
```

Another way of doing this using `subset` as below:

```
subset(df, !duplicated(subset(df, select=c(id, gender))))

#   id  gender variant
# 1  1  Female     a
# 3  1    Male     c
# 4  2  Female     d
# 5  2    Male     e
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a `dplyr` based solution in case you are interested (edited to include [Gregor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor)'s suggestions)

```r
library(dplyr)
group_by(df, id, gender) %>% slice(1)

#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#> # Groups:   id, gender [4]
#>      id gender variant
#>   <dbl> <fctr>  <fctr>
#> 1     1 Female       a
#> 2     1   Male       c
#> 3     2 Female       d
#> 4     2   Male       e
```

It might also be worth using the `arrange` function as well depending on which values of `variant` should be removed.

Comment: Updated `dplyr` can now just do `dplyr::distinct(df, id, gender, .keep_all=TRUE)`; when run in `iris`, this is about 6-7x faster than `group_by`/`slice`.